# How can dotnet ef migrations script produce a script per migration?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, pipeline

I would like to upgrade my databases at deployment time. As I can see I have two choices:

1. Write a tool that calls the `Migrate()` method as described in https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/handling-entity-framework-core-database-migrations-in-production-part-2/#1b-calling-context-database-migrate-via-a-console-app-or-admin-command
2. Use the `dotnet ef migrations script ... --idempotent` command to produce one upgrade script as described in https://clearmeasure.com/run-ef-core-migrations-in-azure-devops/

I like the second approach more, because I do not want to write a tool. However, I have a problem with monolithic scripts. The `dotnet ef migrations script` has the potential to produce quite a big script. Unless I read the last migration from the database myself.

Ideally, I would like to have a Sql script per migration committed to the version control, because producing one monolithic script is going to accumulate cost with time.

What is the idiomatic way to produce Sql script per migration, instead of one monolithic script?

**EDIT 1**

My preferences may be wrong (because I have little experience with EF Core), so  I am open for the first option too.

The version control requirement is not a must either, if we can generate the Sql code for just the missing migrations (in the second approach).

We use Azure DevOps Server 2019 on prem for the pipeline. Soon to be upgraded to 2020.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument for applying migrations at deployment time is so that you don't have to remember to do it manually, then I would definitely go with option #1. By making a custom tool, you can also check if the developer forgot to make a migration, and refuse to deploy.

With option 2, you could forget to add the SQL migration for a C# migration, and the code will still compile and the deployment will still succeed. It still comes down to the developer having to remember to do extra stuff when they make a migration.

Comment: How can a custom tool check if the developer forgot to add a migration?

Comment: I assume there will be a way to call the dotnet tools from within C#, so you can compare the model snapshot with the current code and see if it matches. Failing that, you could create a temporary migration and check if the model snapshot is changed. This will tell you if a developer has modified the ORM classes without adding a corresponding migration

Comment: Would be fantastic to have some more concrete details. Right now I am failing to see how your reply answers my question. Maybe I need to rephrase my question. I will now.

Comment: Ok, so after the update I can see you present two options, and the question is *how do I implement option 2*, not *which option should I choose*. I would not recommend option 2. If you want a sql script per migration, you're going to have to implement a custom tool to split the monolithic script. You may as well just implement option 1. And if you want the generated sql scripts to be in source control, then it becomes an extra step for developers to remember. Also, what software are you using to automate your deployments? There is a good chance the tool you want already exists.